# Postman 4.9.3 - No Interceptor Switch

Tags: asp.net-mvc, postman

I am following along a brilliant Pluralsight tutorial, building my first ASP.Net MVC site. I want to login to my website, creating a cookie in my Chrome browser, and use Postman to send some requests which should be handled by my controller because the Authorize attribute should be satisfied by my browser.

I have installed the interceptor plug-in on my Chrome browser. I keep seeing that I need to switch on the Interceptor at the top of Postman, but I don't have that switch! I have a Proxy Settings button instead.

Can someone please explain how I should proceed?

Comment: version 5.*.* has the extension swith, but later version has not

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a few options here. The tutorial you are watching is probably referring to the Chrome Extension which is what Postman started out as. It now also has a standalone application version, which, at the time of this post, is up to 4.9.3 and for which the interceptor no longer works with.

So you either need to install the Chrome extension version or work with the standalone app without the interceptor.

**Options 1**: Uninstall the standalone app version and install [the Chrome extension version](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop/related?hl=en) and then also make sure to install and enable the [Postman Interceptor Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-interceptor/aicmkgpgakddgnaphhhpliifpcfhicfo)

**Option 2**: Just add a Cookie header to your standalone Postman app's request. Something like:

Key: Cookie

Value: CookieName=28789ijnbskjhiuhyd8y

**Option 3**: Use the standalone app's built in proxy which will allow any requests made through your browser to be streamed into the Postman history. This option works ok but you would have to get the request in your Postman history and then re-execute the request from within Postman which is kind of awkward. [Instructions here](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/capture_native)

Comment: What a brilliant reply, thanks. I think I will try both option 1 and 2 and see which I prefer to work with.